# Explicitly depend on extra source file when recompiling

Tags: haskell, cabal

Say I have an extra file describing some data structure. In one Haskell module I have a TH declaration that takes the contents of that file and generates data types.

How do I force that module to recompile every time that external file changes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the addDependentFile function.

https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-7.15/template-haskell-2.11.0.0/Language-Haskell-TH-Syntax.html#v:addDependentFile